# boto3 S3 upload using aws key

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

The boto3 documentation recommend to configure key from the command line. If there anyway I can put the AWS key into the python source code? Below are the code for reference.

```
If you have the AWS CLI, then you can use its interactive configure command to set up your credentials and default region:
aws configure
Follow the prompts and it will generate configuration files in the correct locations for you.

import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    print(obj.key)
```

Comment: Not recommended.  If key revoked and new key assigned and change made to the credential file. Connection will failed due to to old key. 
Maybe you can add multiple profile and call particular profile.
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/21

Answer (score 13):

See under 'Method Parameters' [in the official documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/configuration.html);

```
from boto3.session import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id='<YOUR ACCESS KEY ID>',
                  aws_secret_access_key='<YOUR SECRET KEY>',
                  region_name='<REGION NAME>')
_s3 = session.resource("s3")
_bucket = _s3.Bucket(<BUCKET NAME>)
_bucket.download_file(Key=<KEY>, Filename=<FILENAME>)
```

Comment: so i do my_s3 = session.resource('s3') to get my s3 object?

Comment: That is what the page says.

Answer (score -1):

Also to download the file with default KMS key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
s3_client.download_file('testtesttest', 'test.txt', '/tmp/test.txt')
```

Here is an example of upload and download an s3 file using KMS

https://www.justdocloud.com/2018/09/21/use-boto3-download_file-aws-kms/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)